# Menu shortcuts in Unix-based systems

Tags: stata

In Stata one can *programmatically* create a menu entry for a dialogue box or a program as follows:

```
window menu append item "stUser" "&Pearly's Program" "db myprogram"
```

In addition, by using the character `&` before `P`, a shortcut is also created. 
This can subsequently be activated simply by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.

Nevertheless, as Stata's Resources and Support [online FAQ](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/db-user/sharing-dialog-menus/) states:

> *"Note: The ampersand & that appears ... is a **Windows-only feature**..."*

Is there a way to assign shortcuts for menu items in Unix-based
versions of Stata (macOS, Linux)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I have come up with so far is to assign a shortcut using a function key (say `F5`):

```
global F5 "db myprogram;"
```

Note that the semi-colon tells Stata to also press enter.

For persistent assignment, the aforementioned code line should be included in the `profile.do` file.

This ensures that it is executed every time Stata starts.